# regex to split an instruction

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a line of assembly code using `split()` method in Java. Here is a sample code:

```
String line = "Add a, b, c";
String[] parts = line.split("[\\s+,]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[Add, a, , b, c]
```

I need the output to be like:

```
[Add, a, b, c]
```

for any of the following inputs:

```
String line = "Add a,b,c";
String line = "Add   a  ,b,c";
String line = "Add a,  b,c";
String line = "Add a,b , c";
String line = "Add a , b , c";
```

or any similar cases.

What is the right regex to use in place of `[\\s+,]`?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? I'd create an array of String[] with the lines you've listed above, and test the regex in a for loop. I think that you'll find that you need to have a comma in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
String[] parts = line.split("[\\s,]+");
```

Your current regex matches exactly one space, or exactly one `+`, or exactly one comma.

The above regex matches one or more spaces and/or commas.

The difference is the placement of the `+`: when it appears inside of a character class, it is interpreted literally.

Comment: I'm betting Eng could have figured this one out with a little nudging. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

How about `[\\s,]+`?  It will match one-or-more occurrances of space-or-comma

Answer (score 0):

try something along the lines of:

**Add  ?([0-9]+) ?, ?([0-9]+) ?, ?([0-9]+) ?"**

**"[Add \1, \2, \3]"**

**([0-9]+)**    should let it take any sized number

**_?**          should make room for an optional space

**\1**          should backreference to the value first found by the first set of ()

**\2**          "       "        "          "        "     "       " second set of ()

**\3**          "       "        "          "        "     "       " third set of ()

The logic is sound but make sure my syntax is correct.